# Banner height and width on load

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a banner. The banner is made with the *width* and a *percentage of the height*. When the body is loaded, it should look good in all resolutions. But, my code does not seem to work. If anyone could take a look at it, it would be greatly appreciated.

```
  <script>
    function load()
    {

      document.write("Available Width: " + Math.round((screen.availWidth)/5));

      a=document.getElementById('banner');
      a.style.width=Math.round((screen.availWidth));
      a.style.height=Math.round((screen.availHeight)/5);
    }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the units for the style properties.

```
a.style.width = … + 'px';
```

Also, use the `var` statement for the `a` variable so that you prevent `a` from leaking to the global scope (if it's not intended).

**Update: Also try removing the `document.write` call.**

Comment: I changed it to                                                  a.style.width=Math.round((screen.availWidth))+'px';
                but it still does not seem to work

Comment: Well, in that case, are you calling the function when the `id="banner"` element is present in the DOM tree? Also try removing the `document.write` line.

Comment: <body onload="load()">
   <div id="banner" style="background-color:#FFD700;">
   </div>
  </body> maybe there is an issue there?

Comment: wow it was the document.write that caused the problem thank you very much

Comment: `document.write` calls should be avoided in most cases. You definitely should not make any after the initial HTML is parsed. `<script>document.write(…);</script>` is fine but calls from, for instance, `window.onload`, `jQuery.ready` or similar are not.